# Parsing HTML with BeatifulSoup class == AND title CONTAINS

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse the following HTML:

```
<div class="product-details">
   <h4 class="title" ><a href="https://productwebpage.com/blue-standard" title="Blue - Standard">Blue - Standard</a></h4>
   <a class="learn-more" data-test-selector="linkViewMoreDetails" href="https://productwebpage.com">Learn More</a>
   <div class="tocart" <a class="" href="/store/addtocartplp?productId=3593" id="AddToCartSimple-3593">Add To Cart</a></div>
</div>
, 
 
<div class="product-details">
   <h4 class="title" ><a href="https://productwebpage.com/blue-wide" title="Blue - Wide">Blue - Wide</a></h4>
   <a class="learn-more" data-test-selector="linkViewMoreDetails" href="https://productwebpage.com">Learn More</a>
   <div class="tocart" <a class="disAddtoCardBtn" href="javascript:void(0)" id="AddToCartSimple-3576" >SOLD</a></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the 'id' where the title contains 'Blue' AND the item is not sold.

I have tried:

```
soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile("Blue"),class_="")
links = soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile("Blue", "Add To Cart"))
ids = [tag["id"] for tag in soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile("Blue"))]
```

But it is not returning the info I'm looking for.

I would like it to return:

```
AddToCartSimple-3593
```

Comment: `href=re.compile("Blue")` This is looking for Blue in the href, not the title...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the data where the "title" contains "Blue" and the item is *not* "SOLD":

1. Use a CSS selector `.product-details > h4 a[title*='Blue']` which will select all `a` where the `title=Blue` under an `h4` under the class `product-details`
2. Find the next `div` using the [`find_next()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) method, and check that the text is not "SOLD".
3. Print the next `div`'s `id`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """<div class="product-details">
   <h4 class="title" ><a href="https://productwebpage.com/blue-standard" title="Blue - Standard">Blue - Standard</a></h4>
   <a class="learn-more" data-test-selector="linkViewMoreDetails" href="https://productwebpage.com">Learn More</a>
   <div class="tocart" <a class="" href="/store/addtocartplp?productId=3593" id="AddToCartSimple-3593">Add To Cart</a></div>
</div>

<div class="product-details">
   <h4 class="title" ><a href="https://productwebpage.com/blue-wide" title="Blue - Wide">Blue - Wide</a></h4>
   <a class="learn-more" data-test-selector="linkViewMoreDetails" href="https://productwebpage.com">Learn More</a>
   <div class="tocart" <a class="disAddtoCardBtn" href="javascript:void(0)" id="AddToCartSimple-3576" >SOLD</a></div>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select(".product-details > h4 a[title*='Blue']"):
    if tag.find_next("div").text != "SOLD":
        print(tag.find_next("div")["id"])
```

Output:

```
AddToCartSimple-3593
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your html is corrupted. You can do the entire filtering with css selectors using `:has`, `:not`, and `:contains` (`:-soup-contains` - latest soupsieve), along with attribute = value selectors. The ^ is a starts with operator, meaning attribute value starts with the string after the =. The ~ is a general sibling combinator and the > is a child combinator. This means looking for a sibling with class (.) `tocart` and then a child with id that starts with `AddToCartSimple-`, but that doesn't have text containing `SOLD` displayed. Less specific than `!="SOLD"` , as it can be a partial string exclusion. Depends on observed variation in actual data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html ='''
  <div class="product-details"> 
   <h4 class="title"><a href="https://productwebpage.com/blue-standard" title="Blue - Standard">Blue - Standard</a></h4> <a class="learn-more" data-test-selector="linkViewMoreDetails" href="https://productwebpage.com">Learn More</a> 
   <div class="tocart"> <a class="" href="/store/addtocartplp?productId=3593" id="AddToCartSimple-3593">Add To Cart</a> 
   </div> 
   <div class="product-details"> 
    <h4 class="title"><a href="https://productwebpage.com/blue-wide" title="Blue - Wide">Blue - Wide</a></h4> <a class="learn-more" data-test-selector="linkViewMoreDetails" href="https://productwebpage.com">Learn More</a> 
    <div class="tocart"> <a class="disAddtoCardBtn" href="javascript:void(0)" id="AddToCartSimple-3576">SOLD</a> 
    </div> 
'''
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('.title:has([title^="Blue -"]) ~ .tocart > [id^=AddToCartSimple-]:not(:contains("SOLD"))')['id'])
```

You should check there was a match before accessing with ['id'] of course. You could also go for all matches as follows:

```
[i['id'] for i in soup.select('.title:has([title^="Blue -"]) ~ .tocart > [id^=AddToCartSimple-]:not(:contains("SOLD"))')]
```

Comment: Yeah, nice!  I knew there was a way with using _only_ CSS selectors.